# Prompted to Update iOS Deployment Target to 12.0 when deployment set to iOS 10.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode12

I have updated to Xcode 12.0.  My app has a deployment target of 10.0 but after updating to Xcode to 12.0, I am getting the following for all the pods in my podfile:

[image: Screenshot 1: Build Settings]

> Update iOS Deployment Target
> This will update the minimum deployment target of Target 'target' to '12.0'.

Why do i need to update the minimum deployment to 12.0 when my minimum deployment for this app is set for 10.0?

Do i uncheck 'Build Settings' and click on Perform Changes or do i update?

Comment: You don't have to do it. Uncheck (note that there could be other types of changes that you may want to perform) & Perform Changes.

Comment: Can you put that in an answer so i can give you credit and close.

Comment: Done. Glad that helped :)

Comment: I don't know if it helped but when i built the project, i am getting errors just in a certain file in GoogleDataTransport pod's file: 'cct.nanopb.h' - 20 errors.  The reason i am using 10.0 as the target so that users using 10.0 and above will be allowed to use this app so updating to 12.0 only will allow anyone only using 12.0 and up, correct?

Comment: Correct. There is no reason to bump up to 12 if you can build for 10 (and hence include more people). The minimum version supported by Xcode 12 is iOS9.

Comment: Before closing this post off, any idea why i am now getting issues after upgrading to Xcode 12 and getting all these errors with GoogleDataTransport pod's file: 'cct.nanopb.h'? or should i start a new post? This happens regardless of whether i update to 12.0 in BuildSettings or not.

Comment: Have you tried to update the pod? You can run a `pod outdated` and see if any new versions are available then you can freeze any pods in your file that you don't need to update (by specifying the currently installed version) & run a `pod update` for the rest.

Comment: I ran pod outdated and the only one that is outdated is Paypal which is deprecated

Comment: Then I would suggest a new question with more details about your setup and the specific errors you get.

Comment: Is there a way to silence this, currently we get it on every Xcode version upgrade..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't have to do it. Uncheck (note that there could be other types of changes that you may want to perform) & Perform Changes, or hit cancel if all changes are for min deployment target.

Answer (score 5):

With Xcode 12.3, the latest as of this writing, you can upgrade the minimum deployment target to iOS 12.0 and support a wide range of devices, according to the latest iOS version of [this matrix](https://dorianroy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/iPhone-Specs-Matrix-1.1.pdf), assuming your users will make the upgrade to iOS 12. It appears the only device left out is the iPhone 5 and 5C. I also [found a complete matrix](https://core-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/asset/uploaded_file/540620/iOS_Device_Matrix_for_Canvas.pdf) that it appears to include all devices and iOS versions.

Answer (score 2):

I faced that kind of problem two years ago ,that sounds weird but I had to keep old Xcode version. I was using Carthage not pods by the way